# How to find the minimum value of a list element which is based on unique value of the same list using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv like the following

```
SKU;price;availability;Title;Supplier
SUV500;21,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
MZ-76E;5,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
SUV500;49,95 €;0;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier2
MZ-76E;71,25 €;0;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier2
SUV500;32,60 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier3
```

I am trying to get as an output a csv that will have the following

```
SKU;price;availability;Title;Supplier
SUV500;21,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
MZ-76E;5,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
```

Where for each SKU I want to get **only** the record in which the price is the minimum

How can I do it because I am totally lost with pandas? with classical if for? with lists?sets?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non pandas solution, this could get your required output.

EDIT: Added csv writer to solution

EDIT: only accept records with '1' in at `row[2]`

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

fin = open('SKU_csv.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8")
csv_reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=';')

fout = open('test_out.csv', 'w', newline = '')
csv_writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';')

csv_writer.writerow(next(csv_reader)) # print header

d = defaultdict(list)

for row in csv_reader:
    if int(row[2]) != 1:
        continue
    key = row[0]
    val = row[1].replace(',', '.')
    price = float(re.search('\d+\.\d+', val).group(0))
    d[key].append([row, price])

fin.close()

for arr in d.values():
    minimum, _ = min(arr, key=itemgetter(1)) # minimum price (at arr idx 1)
    csv_writer.writerow(minimum)

fout.close()


'''
*** test_out.csv contents

SKU;price;availability;Title;Supplier
SUV500;21,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
MZ-76E;5,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
'''
```

Comment: float(re.search('\d+\.\d+', val).group(0)) is not working with group, and some SKU of products display something like korean?! characters in front

Comment: I can't guess why group(0) is not working for you. I worked for me given your sample data. Perhaps you could edit your post to include some of the lines that have those characters. Then get back to me and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: For the characters I added  encoding="utf8" for the writing I think its ok, and for the price I did price = float(val) , what re.search is doing together with group?

Comment: @Nikos If its working for you, ok. The regular expression `re.search(...` is looking for the digits to convert to a float

Comment: How can be improved so as to get the minimum based on availability 1?

Comment: @Nikos I made the change to only accept records with 1 in the third column.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas you can do the following

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('your file')
```

As andy pointed out below this returns only the price and SKU columns

```
df_reduced= df.groupby('SKU')['price'].min()
```

for all the columns you can change the groupby to a list of all the columns you want to keep

```
df_reduced= df.groupby(['SKU', 'availability', 'Title', 'Supplier'])['price'].min()
```

Comment: and how to test print, print(df_reduced) ?

Comment: yes exactly. what you will notice is the SKU is going to take place of the index and if you don't want that you can add as_index=False to the groupby like this

df.groupby('SKU', as_index=False)['price'].min()

Comment: is the column name in the file SKU all caps like that or something else? Its basically saying you aren't putting the correct name for the sku in there. You can get the exact one is using by putting df.columns[0] (or whatever number the SKU column is in place of 0) in place of 'SKU' in the groupby.

Comment: Your answer returns a dataframe with 2 columns while he wants his result return all columns(after using as_index=False)

Comment: @D.Sanders: your edited answer returns all rows where combinations of 'SKU', 'availability', 'Title', 'Supplier' are unique and all columns after groupby and min. He wants a single min('price') row with all columns for each 'SKU'

Comment: And how I will export it to a new csv?

Comment: @D.Sanders still is not working because of keyerror on SKU but csv has SKU not sku neither empty spaces etc

Comment: @D.Sanders I put df = pd.read_csv('final_csv.csv', delimiter =';') and it is working.. so all those are the products based on minimum price

Comment: ok cool. if you look at the edit i made based on what andy said you should be able to get al lthe columns.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:** *taking out the previous confusing assumption*

After reading from csv file

```
In [8]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';', encoding='utf-8')

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
          SKU    price  availability             Title   Supplier
0      SUV500  21,50 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier1
1      MZ-76E   5,50 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier1
2      SUV500  49,95 €             0  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier2
3      MZ-76E  71,25 €             0  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier2
4      SUV500  32,60 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier3
```

Add a new columns to hold the float value of `price`

```
In [12]:  df['f_price'] = df['price'].str.extract(r'([+-]?\d+\,\d+)', expand=False).str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
#Note: if your locality using denotion `,` for decimal point, you don't need additional `str.replace`. Just use below
#df['f_price'] = df['price'].str.extract(r'([+-]?\d+\,\d+)', expand=True).astype(float)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
          SKU    price  availability             Title   Supplier  f_price
0      SUV500  21,50 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier1    21.50
1      MZ-76E   5,50 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier1     5.50
2      SUV500  49,95 €             0  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier2    49.95
3      MZ-76E  71,25 €             0  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier2    71.25
4      SUV500  32,60 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier3    32.60
```

Get the list of min(f_price) per group from groupby

```
In [28]: idxmin_list = df.groupby('SKU', as_index=False)['f_price'].idxmin().tolist()

In [29]: idxmin_list
Out[29]: [1, 0]
```

Finally, passing `idxmin_list` to `df` and drop `f_price` column to get the final result

```
In [33]: df_final = df.loc[idxmin_list].drop('f_price', 1)

In [34]: df_final
Out[34]:
      SKU    price  availability             Title   Supplier
1  MZ-76E   5,50 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier1
0  SUV500  21,50 €             1  27-03-2019 14:46  supplier1
```

Write to csv file

```
In [65]: df_final.to_csv('Sku_min.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

File `Sku_min.csv` is created in your working folder and its content is

```
SKU;price;availability;Title;Supplier
MZ-76E;5,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
SUV500;21,50 €;1;27-03-2019 14:46;supplier1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to use pandas here. This may not be the *optimal* solution but it'd be mine:

```
import csv

class Product:
    def __init__(self, sku, price, availability, title, supplier):
        self.sku = sku
        self.price = float(price.replace(',', '.')[:-2]) # allows sorting 
        self.availability = availability
        self.title = title
        self.supplier = supplier

unparsed_products = []

with open('name_of_csv.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    next(csv_reader) # to skip past header line when parsing.
    for row in csv_reader:
        p = Product(*row)
        unparsed_products.append(p)

suv500_products = [i for i in unparsed_products if i.sku == 'SUV500']
lowest_priced_suv500_product = sorted(suv500_products, key=lambda x: x.price, reverse=True)[0] # gets the first entry from the sorted list of suv500_products
print(lowest_priced_suv500_product.price)
>>> 21.50
```

You could easily extend this out to cover other products by changing the value of X in `if i.sku == X` .

Comment: I get that self.price = float(self.price.replace(',', '.')[:-2]) # allows sorting , Product object has no attribute price

Comment: Sorry about that - I was referring to `self.price` before it was defined.  That line is fixed now.

Comment: Value Error on price could not convert string to float: 'pri' I added .replace('€','') but I get the same

Comment: Okay - that error is referring to the header line of the CSV. I have updated the code block to include a line to skip that and marked it with a comment. I've been spoiled by pyspark lately where you can just do `headers=True` and the rest is magic :-)

Comment: Magic indeed but how to add the corresponded supplier of the price? :)

Comment: You'd do something like `print(lowest_priced_suv500_product.supplier, lowest_priced_suv500_product.price)` to get that info to print as well.

Comment: aa as class attribute! :)

Comment: Thank you!!!! n1c9 Additionaly for all skus I added i.sku==p.sku correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190783/discussion-between-nikos-and-n1c9).